How to put common data in seeds and fixtures on Ruby-on-Rails?
I would like to assign identical data to some of the records for seeds for DB-initialization and fixtures for testing on Ruby-on-Rails, without violating the DRY principle.
For example, let us consider the case where a model Genre has a user-editable attribute of description and semi-permanently-fixed attributes of mname and priority, which are tightly interconnected to the model and some algorithms.  As for the latter two, they can (and should?) be defined as a constant in the model, and both the seeds and fixtures (easily) refer to it, like the following.
 # Model /app/models/genre.rb
PRIORITY = {novel: 3, poem: 5}.with_indifferent_access

 # Seeds /db/seeds.rb
s="novel"; Genre.create!(mname: s, priority: Genre::PRIORITY[s],
             description: "Various novels")
s="poem";  Genre.create!(mname: s, priority: Genre::PRIORITY[s],
             description: "Favourite poems")

 # Fixtures /test/fixtures/genres.yml
novel:
  mname: novel
  priority: <%= Genre::PRIORITY[:novel] %>
  description: "Various novels"

poem:
  mname: poem
  priority: <%= Genre::PRIORITY[:poem] %>
  description: "Favourite poems"

In this example, the values of description are definied separately in the seeds and fixtures, manually set to the identical values. This goes against the DRY principle.  I would rather like to define them at a single place so that both seeds and fixtures can refer to them without ambiguity.
Where should I put them and how can I refer to them?
Unlike the hard-coded priority, I am afraid a constant in a model (or code in lib/ or config/) is not the right place to define the initial value of the user-editable parameter description, as (1) it can change any time and (2) it is irrelevant to run the application. The values are relevant only for seeding and testing (as initial values) so that the outputs in the development and test environments look similar.

Given "(1) it can change any time and (2) it is irrelevant to run the application." I do not see how this violates DRY nor do I understand "The values are relevant only for seeding and testing (as initial values) so that the outputs in the development and test environments look similar", as the fact that these values happen to be the same is neither an actual requirement nor relevant according to your post. Can you please clarify why this needs to be the case?

@engineersmnky It is not mandatory for the app to work. However, I have found it is best to make the outputs in the development (based on seeds) and test environments (based on fixtures) appear similar in principle (see the last sentence in my question) as the starting point, though testing should cover a much broader context, too. Otherwise you might encouter the situations where the app works in only one of the environments and you scratch the head… This is particularly the case for system tests, where you may use screenshots for comparison. I think consistency is important.

The OP wants part of initial (fixture) data in the test database (DB) to be as close as possible to the real (development, production) DB, which would minimize the possibility of errors suppressed only in the test environment or conversely errors arising in the test environment only that would never arise in the other environments in real situations. Besides, if what you see in screenshots in the test environment during system tests is very similar to what you see in the development environment, it is reassuring.
As the OP says, the table data in the DB that are tightly connected to an algorithm of the app should be defined in the app/ (or conf/) directory and be read in DB initializations, be it for the test or development environment. But the data that are not essential for the app, including some or most seeds for DB initialization, should not be. I think the directory under db/, perhaps (user-created) db/seeds/ is the appropriate place to put such data in. Other possibilities may include a directory under lib/, such as lib/assets/ .
Using the OP's case with model Genre, the following is one of the ways to implement a case scenario of this type.
Suppose the model assumes there is a Genre record with a unique attribute mname: "novel" associated with a fixed priority of 3 and so on (be it perpetually or in some occassions or conditions).  You create a directory db/seeds/ first.
Model
 ## Model /app/models/genre.rb
class Genre < ApplicationRecord
  # defines algorithm-related constants.
  PRIORITY = {novel: 3, poem: 5}.with_indifferent_access
end

Seed data in db/ (defined in a module)
in which the above-described Model data are read.
 ## Seeds /db/seeds/genre.rb
module Seeds
  module Genre
    # Data to seed (descriptions are defined here)
    SEED_DATA = [["novel", "Various novels"],
                 ["poem", "Favourite poems"]].map{ |ea|
      [ea[0], {mname: ea[0],
               priority: Genre::PRIORITY[ea[0]],
               description: ea[1], }.with_indifferent_access ]
    }.to_h.with_indifferent_access
  end
end

Seeds script (default for Development),
in which the above-described seed data are read.
 ## Seeds /db/seeds.rb
require_relative "seeds/genre.rb"

Seeds::Genre::SEED_DATA.each_pair do |ek, ev|
  record = Genre.find_or_initialize_by(mname: ev[:mname]}
  next if record.new_record?
  # If a record with the mname exists, do nothing, so that
  # this seeding script can be run multiple times without reverting
  # deliberate changes in production back to the original.
  record.update!(ev)
end

Setting for the test environment
 ## /test/test_helper.rb
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
require 'rails/test_help'

Dir[Rails.root+"db/seeds/*.rb"].uniq.each do |seed_file|
  require seed_file
end

ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.context_class.include Seeds

Fixtures data for testing,
in which the above-described seed data, which partially contain Model constants, are read.
 ## Fixtures /test/fixtures/genres.yml
<% Seeds::Genre::SEED_DATA.each_pair do |ename, ehash| %>
  <% ehash.each_pair do |ek, edata| %>
genre_<%= ename %>:
  <%= ek %>: <%= edata %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>


Here, the keys are

to define the seed data in db/seeds/, where some data are read from the model,
to require and include the seed data for the test environment, defined in /test/test_helper.rb, and
for the fixture to read the seed data, where the power of ERB is exploited.

NOTE: The example above puts a direct input from a Ruby String to YAML. Generally speaking, the value should be processed to be YAML-safe, especially a long string potentially including new lines.
With these, you can guarantee a (maybe partially) identical data set between the seeds and test-fixtures, basically eliminating the risk of inconsistent data while maintaining the flexibility to register additional data to the fixture, and also you can (sometimes greatly) reduce the amount of lines in the fixtures.
Consult Rails Reference for detail about the fixture settings.
